# Reusing methods in go which operate on struct values

Tags: go, inheritance, composition

I am trying to share a single method across multiple structs in go. I do not want to have to redefine the method across every struct.

I realise that code reusability in go is achieved by using composition over inheritance. However I have no idea how to use the concept in my current use case. My code is the following:

```
package mypackage

import (
    "net/url"
    "reflect"
)


// Build a query string from a query struct
func (params ListShipmentsQuery) toQueryString() string {
    query := url.Values{}
    values := reflect.ValueOf(params)
    types := values.Type()
    for i := 0; i < values.NumField(); i++ {
        value := values.Field(i).Interface().(string)
        if value != "" {
            query.Add(types.Field(i).Tag.Get("url"), value)
        }

    }

    return query.Encode()
}

type ListShipmentsQuery struct {
    ShipmentId string `url:"shipment_id"`
    OrderId string `url:"order_id"`
}

type ListProductsQuery struct {
    Sku string `url:"sku"`
    Name string `url:"name"`
}
```

How can I apply the same method to the `ListProductsQuery` struct without repeating myself? The method must use the properties that make up the struct.

For example in PHP using inheritance I would do:

```
class Parent 
{
    public function toQueryString()
    {
        // Logic to grab properties and build query string
    }
}

class Child {}

$c = new Child();
$query_string = $c.toQueryString();
```

I have tried implementing another struct via composition but I have no way of passing the "parent's" properties to the struct which will have the shared method.

Comment: Have you considered implementing the func as `func toQueryString(params any) string`?

Comment: @ZekeLu that was my original implementation, but I’m using this as a learning exercise. I’d therefore like to wrap my head around it, but if it’s not possible or an anti-pattern then I’ll fall back to this

Comment: It's not an anti-pattern. But it just seems not necessary. I haven't tried it, but composition should work. It's boring to embed a field into every struct. If there is not a good reason, the plain func solution is preferred.

Comment: @ZekeLu How would one achieve this with composition though?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I can not find a way to achieve this with composition. The promoted method doesn't know to which type it's promoted.

Comment: Go does not have inheritance. You can't define methods on structs or interfaces that can be used by other strings and interfaces. To my understanding `func toQueryString(params any) string` is about as close as you can get. I will reply with an answer using generics, but it won't help much.

Answer (score 3):

here's an example using generics, I would still probably go for the simple function example suggested in the comments, but this is surely useful for certain cases:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    {

        p := Parent[ListShipmentsQuery]{}
        p.child.ShipmentId = "hi"
        p.child.OrderId = "hi"
        fmt.Println(p.toQueryString())
    }
    {

        p := Parent[ListProductsQuery]{}
        p.child.Sku = "hi"
        p.child.Name = "hi"
        fmt.Println(p.toQueryString())
    }
}

type Parent[C any] struct {
    child C
}

func (p *Parent[C]) toQueryString() string {
    query := url.Values{}
    values := reflect.ValueOf(p.child)
    types := values.Type()
    for i := 0; i < values.NumField(); i++ {
        value := values.Field(i).Interface().(string)
        if value != "" {
            query.Add(types.Field(i).Tag.Get("url"), value)
        }

    }
    return query.Encode()
}

type ListShipmentsQuery struct {
    ShipmentId string `url:"shipment_id"`
    OrderId    string `url:"order_id"`
}

type ListProductsQuery struct {
    Sku  string `url:"sku"`
    Name string `url:"name"`
}
```